# Me gustaría modificar este programa para simplificarlo aún más

Tags: c#

Tengo este programa que ordena alafabeticamente las palabras ingresadas por el usuario, pero el usuario debe digitar el numero de palabras que quiere acomodar antes de todo, viendose así:

[image: imagen del funcionamiento del programa]

Me gustaría que el usuario no tenga que digitar cuantas palabras quiere ingresar.
Mi idea es que el usuario ingrese palabras y que cuando ya no quiera no digite nada y así se le ordenarían alfabeticamente.

No sé si esto sea posible y no se me ocurren formas de hacerlo, agradecería la ayuda.

Aquí está el codigo actualmente:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = LeeN();         
        string[] arreglo = new string[n]; //se define el arreglo de n espacios ingresados anteriormente
        
        //ciclo for donde se inicia una variable i, a la que se le asigne 1, mientras que i sea menor o igual a n (cantidad de numeros) se va acumulando 1 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //ciclo de lectura de datos
        {
            LeeDatos(arreglo, n, i);                  
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Palabras ordenadas alfabeticamente");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //ciclo para mostrar los datos hasta n
        {
            ImprimeDatos(arreglo, n, i);         
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int LeeN ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de palabras que desea acomodar alfabeticamente");
        //se crea una variable n en donde se guarda cuantos valores se quieren calcular
         int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
         return n;
    }

    public static string LeeDatos(string[] arreglo, int n, int i)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una palabra");
         arreglo[i] = Console.ReadLine().ToLower(); //guarda lo que digita el usuario en el arreglo directamente                                                    
             return arreglo[i];
    }

    public static string Burbuja(string[] arreglo, int n, int i)
    {
        string orden;
        for (int x = i + 1; x < n; x++) //el for segundo es el que hace las comparaciones uno por encima de i hasta llegar a n
        {
            if (arreglo[i].CompareTo(arreglo[x]) > 0) //si el dato de la primera posición es mayor que la siguiente posición
            {
                orden = arreglo[i]; //se le asigna a orden el dato que tiene en la posición i
                arreglo[i] = arreglo[x]; //realiza el cambio a i 
                arreglo[x] = orden; //se le asigna a x el dato que tenía i, intercambiandolos
            }
        }
        return arreglo[i];
    }

    public static string ImprimeDatos(string[] arreglo, int n, int i)
    {
        //IMPRIME INFORMACIÓN
        arreglo[i] = Burbuja(arreglo, n, i);
        Console.WriteLine(arreglo[i]);

        return arreglo[i];
    } 

}
```

Antes de soluciones agradecería explicaciones para entender el funcionamiento, muchas gracias por la atención

Comment: si se puede, usa otro tipo de datos p.e una lista(List) o vectores dinamicos. Estos gestionan la memoria según se necesita. Y si lees un punto '.' finalizas de leer.

Comment: Me gustaría no tener que cambiar los tipos de datos, no hay alguna forma de hacerlo con el arreglo?

Comment: Si, podrías pero no son formas validas porque no son eficientes y coges malos vicios de la programacion

Comment: Entiendo, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Buenas una simplificación usando linq en vez de la función burbuja

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de palabras que desea acomodar alfabeticamente");
    //se crea una variable n en donde se guarda cuantos valores se quieren calcular
     int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        string[] arreglo = new string[n]; //se define el arreglo de n espacios ingresados anteriormente

        //ciclo for donde se inicia una variable i, a la que se le asigne 1, mientras que i sea menor o igual a n (cantidad de numeros) se va acumulando 1 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //ciclo de lectura de datos
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una palabra");
            arreglo[i] = Console.ReadLine().ToLower(); //guarda lo que digita el usuario en el arreglo directamente                                                    
        }
        arreglo = arreglo.OrderBy(item =>item).ToArray();//ordena por ASCII que esta alfabeticamente los caracteres i lo convierte en array
        Console.WriteLine("Palabras ordenadas alfabeticamente");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //ciclo para mostrar los datos hasta n
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arreglo[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: La idea del programa es aprender a utilizar los metodos de ordenamiento, igualmente agradezco mucho tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Por definición en C# (y en todos los lenguajes decentes) un array es una estructura de datos de tamaño estático.  En cambio las Listas son de tamaño dinamico.

Ahora, para darte una solución, puedes concatenar un string, es decir guardar todas las palabras en un único string separando por espacio (como si fuera una oración) y luego haces un [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split). Además debes escoger una palabra que haga de parada. Yo lo haré con "" es decir un string vacío

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string entradas = "";
    string palabra = "";
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una palabra");
        palabra = Console.ReadLine()!.ToLower();

        entradas += " " + palabra; //concatemaos un espacio + la nueva palabra

    } while (palabra != "");


    //con trim sacamos los espacios del principio y final de la oracionb
    string[] arreglo = entradas.Trim().Split(' '); //ahora tenemos un arreglo de palabras
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MAX es el numero máximo de palabra que una persona puede introducir por teclado
La introducción de datos se termina con un . y final.

```
   int n;
   const int MAX=100000;//Esto es una estimación habría que ajustarla
            
    string[] arreglo = new string[MAX];
    for ( n = 0; n < MAX; n++) //ciclo de lectura de datos
    {
     if (LeeDatos(arreglo, MAX, n)==".") break;                  
    }
    n=n-1;// quitamos el punto
```

Es la mejor solución que se me ocurre con tus requisitos y apenas tienes que cambiar código. Problema uso excesivo de memoria.

- Nota:
  Pasar MAX a LeerDatos no sirve en esta implementación.